# Unzip a R object straight from the environment

Tags: r, binary, unzip

I have a R object (class: 'raw') loaded into the environment. It's in a binary format. I know this (zipped) R object contains a single file (e.g. a pdf or txt file).

Let's call this object: 'zipped_r_object'.

I do not have the original file saved on my computer. This object is fetched from a databaseconnection.

That is why I want to unzip the binary/raw 'zipped_r_object' directly from the R-environment and save the unzipped content in a new object ('unzipped_object'). This way, I can process the file further.

How can I do this in R? I know how to unzip from a saved zip-archive saved on my computer. But I can't seem to this exclusively in the R environment.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to `writeBin` the object out to a file.

```
writeBin(zipped_r_object, "temp.zip")
```

You could also write it out to a temp file and then use `unzip` with `list = TRUE` to see the name of the file contained in the archive.

```
temp <- tempfile()
writeBin(zipped_r_object, temp)
unzip(temp, list = TRUE)
```

Then you could extract it to a temp directory:

```
temp2 <- tempdir()
unzip(temp, temp2)
list.files(temp2)
```

Comment: This works for me! You set me on the right track with the (necessary) writeBin-function. Was hoping to do all in memory, but can't win them all. Thanks for the compact and complete answer.

Comment: Agreed, this seems like it could be slow or clunky... Would love to know if there is a way to do it in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I once faced a similar problem. After an API request I got a zipped binary file which I had to parse in the following way:

```
response.from.API.object
object.as.string.b64.binary = response.from.API.object$content
object.as.string.b64.dec = jsonlite::base64_dec(object.as.string.b64.binary)
base::writeBin(object.as.string.b64.dec, destination.fpath)
```

I think your `zipped_r_object` would be equivalent to my `object.as.string.b64.binary`

In my case I had to write the object to disk and then work from there.

Comment: Thnx for your post! I upvoted your comment since the solution was the writeBin-function (to write to disk and take it from there).But I have to mark the answer of Ian Campbell as 'correct'. His answer was compact & complete.